# What is maximum distance iPhone's TrueDepth Camera can measure?

Tags: iphone, camera

Is there range limit to iPhone true depth camera? I searched for this for a day, but couldn't find any useful info. The appropriate minimum range is 150 mm but what is the maximum distance that iPhone's TrueDepth camera can measure with useable accuracy?

Comment: Did you conduct any experiments ?

Comment: I don't have an iPhone to conduct this experiment